The generalized eigenproblem with PSD matrices.
For a generalized eigenvalue problem:
$$Av_k=λ_k Bv_k$$
If we assume that both $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ are both positive definite, many papers [1-3] have documented relevant conclusions:
$$λ_k^{\prime}=v_k^{T} (A^{\prime}-λ_k B^{\prime})v_k$$
$$v_{k}^{\prime}=-\frac{1}{2}v_kv_{k}^{T}B^{\prime}v_k+\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
 j=1\\
 j\ne k\\
\end{array}}^N{\frac{v_jv_{j}^{\mathrm{T}}(A^{\prime}-\lambda _kB^{\prime})v_k}{(\lambda _k-\lambda _j)}}$$
where $()^{\prime}$ denotes a first-order partial derivative w.r.t. a parameter.
However, if $A$ and $B$ are only positive semi-definite, meaning that many of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ will be zero, can the related conclusions (i.e., Eq.(2-3)) still be applied? Will this have a bad impact on the results? Could you provide some insight or suggest any references that I can consult to continue the first and second order partial derivatives for the non-zero eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors with PSD $A$ and $B$?
Reference

Murthy, D. V., & Haftka, R. T. (1988). Derivatives of eigenvalues
and eigenvectors of a general complex matrix. International Journal
for Numerical Methods in Engineering, 26(2), 293-311.
Lin, R. M., Mottershead, J. E., & Ng, T. Y. (2020). A
state-of-the-art review on theory and engineering applications of
eigenvalue and eigenvector derivatives. Mechanical Systems and
Signal Processing, 138, 106536.
Overton, M. L., & Womersley, R. S. (1995). Second derivatives for
optimizing eigenvalues of symmetric matrices. SIAM Journal on Matrix
Analysis and Applications, 16(3), 697-718.

Thanks in advance!
